# c# - Export DataGridView to PDF code generating error

Tags: c#, datagridview, export, export-to-pdf

My code to export the application data to PDF includes four parts. First a logo is put on top of PDF, then two lines of paragraph, then a table with some details, then the DataGridView table.

Everything except DataGridView is getting printed on PDF. The DataGridView table is not forming on PDF, the error being returned is "object reference not set to an instance of an object" and I cannot arrive at the fault in the code.

Below is the error ScreenShot

[image: Error ScreenShot]

Below is the code.

```
                        dataGridView1.Columns
                            .OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
                            .ToList()
                            .ForEach(c => Table.AddCell(c.Name));
                        //rows
                        dataGridView1.Rows
                            .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                            .ToList()
                            .ForEach(r =>
                            {
                                var cells = r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().ToList();
                                cells.ForEach(c => Table.AddCell(c.Value.ToString()));
                            });
```

Comment: _the error being returned is "object reference not set to an instance of an object"_ Which line does throw this? What does the debugger tell you about the object? - Does the header get created?

Comment: @TaW the Debugger is not showing any error. The software is launching perfectly. Only when I click the save button it flows to "Catch" from "Try" and shows error. But even then a PDF is being created and saved with all the elements, except the DataGridView Table.

Comment: @TaW yes header table gets created.

Comment: OK, the debugger can't act as you have wrapped the code in a try/catch clause. Does the Messgebox come up? You may want to put a breakpoint on it and look closer into the exception..

Comment: @TaW yes, the MessageBox comes up. Maybe I should try without the try catch clause.

Comment: No, you should analyse the exception fully. It ought to tell you the line, afair

Comment: @TaW I have been trying all variations that I could think of but this error is not eliminated. The debugger is not showing any warning or error even when I remove Try Catch clause. I am new to programming. Please take a look and see if you can find the mistake. I have edited my question to include screenshot of the error being returned.

Comment: Hm. I just tried to re-create the error but I can't. Here the pdf gets created, including dgv data. Note that all data, including the headers are put into one single table row and only as far as the space allows. If I had more columns the space would have run out with the headers before any real data could be placed. You probaly need to include code to advance the table rows. While quite impressive this way to use linq for super-compact code it is really hard to debug. I would avoid it and got for plain old double loops.. -

Comment: Ha, I just tested the idea of adding a lot more columns a lo and behold your error comes up. It is caused by __unfilled (null) cells__! - Note that the VS debugger popped up and told me all about it! Aren't you using build for debug in the project properties? The ex.StackTrace show the last line that was called at the top, but it can't just break there due to the catch.. - Anyway this line `cells.ForEach(c => Table.AddCell(c.Value.ToString()));` breaks when `c.Value` is null.. This would be a quich and dirty fix : `cells.ForEach(c => Table.AddCell(c.Value == null ? "" :  c.Value.ToString()));`

Comment: @TaW Hey, that worked beautifully, thanks...

Comment: @TaW just one more query. I had set the visibility of the ID column in datagridview to false, but its still coming into the PDF. Any way of eliminating this column?

Comment: This will filter invisible columns: `var cells = r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().Where(x => x.Visible).ToList();`

Comment: @Taw Again, this too worked beautifully. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Taw One thing is giving me trouble after the Setup file is created. This ITextSharp Image which I use has a link. Of course the target computer would not have the image at the same location as this link. I had a similar problem for the connection string of database but that I was able to solve using Data Source connection string. What could be the solution of this image problem?

Comment: That fully depends on g how you design the data storage. Realive paths are one option. But this should/could be a separate question..

Comment: @TaW Thanks, I managed to solve it. Apparently file path isn't needed if the image is in the debug. Just need to write file name. I did post a separate question too. Maybe I should answer it if it benefits anyone else..

Comment: _if the image is in the debug_ Yes and for better structuring you can put them in an image forder and prefix the fielname with that folder but without root etc.. - Tis is called a 'relative path'.

Comment: @TaW aha...will remember that, thanks

Comment: @TaW need your help in another area pls. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63979827/14309887